# Sine wave using Arduino uno

Tags: arduino

I am an Arduino hobbyist, I want to make sine wave using Arduino Uno,
for that i using timer0 as interrupt, OCR0A set to 17 for 3.6khz interrupt(16000000/(100hz*36 interval)/256-1),
If I am using only one pwm pin I am getting correct frequency but when I enable two pwm pin I am getting only half of the frequency, kindly advise what is wrong and how to correct it.
.................................
This code I am getting correct frequency at PWM pin 9.

```
 ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect)
{
OCR1A=(256+((((sin(num*3.14/180))*256))))/2;
//OCR1B=(256+((((sin(num*3.14/180))*256))))/2;
     num=num+10;
    if(num >= 360)
{
       num = 0;   
    }
}
```

............................
This code I am getting only half of the previous frequency at PWM pin 9,10

```
ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect)
{
OCR1A=(256+((((sin(num*3.14/180))*256))))/2;
OCR1B=(256+((((sin(num*3.14/180))*256))))/2;
     num=num+10;
    if(num >= 360)
{
       num = 0;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Could be done in a very simple way using sound libraries, for instance [Mozzi](https://sensorium.github.io/Mozzi/).

Comment: I'm curious... what happens when you don't do the second calculation and set OCR1B to the same value as OCR1A? Does the rate come back up? I'm not sure how fast the ATmega382 can do floating point math and trigonometric functions. Also, those constants are `double`s... use `1.0f` for single-precision float. Maybe try this: have a pre-made lookup table of 36 values (every 10 degrees, like you're doing), and step through it in the interrupt routine, to avoid all the excess calculations.

Comment: please give us complete test code so we can take a look and test its.